# jquery ui autocomplete fails to respond when refresh data is very huge

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am using ajax to refresh data source of jquery `autocomplete` for search functionality.When user makes a search with a single letter, db returns > 3 thousand records. In that case widget stops to respond. Please find my code below.

```
$("#customer_serach").autocomplete({
  source: [],
  search: function(event, ui) {
    searchKey = $.trim($(this).val());
    //alert(searchKey);
    populateClientDetails(searchKey);
  }
});

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  async: true,
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      if (key == 'customerDetails') {
        var customerDetails = data.customerDetails;
        $.each(customerDetails,
          function(key, value) {
            customer_list
              .push(value);
          });
      }
    });
    $("#customer_serach").autocomplete("option", "source", customer_list);
  }
})
```

Is this a code issue or needs to restrict the number of records fetched from db when user searches with a single letter search key.

Comment: Why not adjust the tolerance to 2 or 3 letters instead of searching on just 1 letter? Use the `minLength` option.

Comment: Also, you can set `source` to a function that can perform the AJAX. Also you could truncate your results to 100 items if you wanted.